# How to set edit Text equals empty android

Tags: android

I get data of Latitude and Longitude from other activity by Intent for data and I set this data into edit text after receiving it in the first activity.

Before I do Intent to data from second activity the first activity works and set into edit text equals  value 0.0

So now I need if edit text equals 0.0 make it (INVISIBLE) and if it equals any number other 0.0 make it  (VISIBLE).

I get this 0.0 from here

```
   Intent i = getIntent();
        Latitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Latitude",0.0);
        Longitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Longitude",0.0);
```

I was try to do something like that:

```
 if (editText.equals(0.0)) {

                editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }else {
                editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 editText.setText(Longitude.toString());

        }
```

but not work

And I send data to first activity by this code:

```
         Bundle b = new Bundle();
                Bundle c = new Bundle();
                b.putDouble("Latitude", Double.parseDouble(Latitude));
                c.putDouble("Longitude", Double.parseDouble(Longitude));
                intent.putExtras(b);
                intent.putExtras(c);
```

How can I make edit text empty  if it equals 0.0 and not VISIBLE?

Please help me if anyone knows the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Simple, Just changed one line from your code

**Your Code**

```
if (editText.equals(0.0)) {

            editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }else {
            editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             editText.setText(Longitude.toString());

    }
```

**Change It to**

```
if (editText.getText().toString().equals("0.0")) {

            editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }else {
            editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             editText.setText(Longitude.toString());

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, my brother, you helped me to get to the solution - a very simple change, I found the solution as follows ===  if (Latitude.equals(0.0)){ } else {} ===

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString()) == 0.0){
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `editText.text.toString().equals("0.0")` in if clause, but what if the location which you give from other activity will be 0.0 and 0.0. In equator we have this conditions. I think it's better that you make edittext **INVISIBLE** and when you come from another activity to this activity make it **VISIBLE**. Or you can change

```
        Latitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Latitude",0.0);
        Longitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Longitude",0.0);
```

to for example

```
        Latitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Latitude",1000.0);
        Longitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Longitude",1000.0);
```

Because 1000.0 is invalid value for latitude and longitude and when you have 1000.0 you know that you haven't come to this activity yet.

Comment: Thank you for your response, my brother, you helped me to get to the solution - a very simple change, I found the solution as follows === if (Latitude.equals(0.0)){ } else {} === Also thank you for clarifying the longitude and latitude point You have helped me to avoid mistakes in the future

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem as follows:

```
 if (Latitude.equals(0.0)){
            editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else {
            editText.setText(Latitude.toString());
            editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```